# Change contents of columns depending on resolution in Bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3, I have:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img ...>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img ...>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img ...>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

which gives:

```
IMG    IMG   IMG

Text   Text  Text
```

and when I go to a smaller screen, it goes to:

```
IMG
Text

IMG
Text

IMG
Text
```

I want to keep the layout for a large page, but for a small page I would like:

```
IMG  Text
IMG  Text
IMG  Text
```

It would be the same thing as:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
      <img ...>
      <img ...>
      <img ...>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
      <p>...</p>
      <p>...</p>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

except that that does not work for a large screen.

I don't know how to say, "When the page is large, img and p should be in the same column, but when the page is small, img and p should be in different columns.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post a JSBin on things that you've tried.

Comment: OK so I just figured out how to do it, but not elegantly: http://jsbin.com/idIqEXaMI/1/edit

Comment: It's helpful to put a natural amount of text and an actual image in the Bin. http://jsbin.com/idIqEXaMI/2/edit. It's the wrong use of the responsive utilities since you're loading images and text twice. You can just use css: http://jsbin.com/idIqEXaMI/4/edit

Comment: Awesome @ChristinaArasmoBeymer thank you! I didn't realize what an easy fix it was with css, and I'm reading up on exactly how clearfix works. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @ChristinaArasmoBeymer your CSS solution doesn't use Bootstrap's features so it makes this unnecessary complicated in my opinion.

Comment: @BassJobsen: Yeah, didn't think about nesting rows until after. But whether it's more complicated, that's debatable, 5 lines of CSS instead of nesting rows and lots of extra classes in the html. And img-responsive should be automatic.

Comment: Thanks @BassJobsen, that actually makes it cleaner for small screens, as it doesn't get strange wrapping when the img and text are different heights.

Comment: And @Christina, thanks for your help. I'm new to all of this so I didn't even realize what you had done was an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nesting (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) to solve your problem:

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">IMG</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">TXT</div>
        </div>  
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">IMG</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">TXT</div>
        </div>  
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">IMG</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">TXT</div>
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

NB make your images responsive by adding class `img-responsive` to it, http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-responsive-images